# Efficient way to convert Pytorch dataset to loader/sampler that samples at least one point from each class

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, dataloader

I'm trying to think of a fast and efficient way to convert a Pytorch dataset into a sampler that samples at least one of each class. So far I've iterated through the Pytorch dataset sequentially and creates a 2D tensor for each class (Batch x Feature) then returns random idxes of each tensor, but that's pretty slow and doesn't leverage a dataloader or sampler. I'm trying to think of a way to set this up into a loader or sampler to be faster.

**Goal:**
So each batch sampled should have at least one representative of each class and it's guaranteed that the batch size given to the sampler will be much larger than the number of classes (Batch size will be at least 2x as large as classes). Ideally each batch shouldn't be sampled with replacement, but a point can be sampled in different batches.

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean ? You want a sampler which makes sure that at least of each class is sampled, but one of each class per what ? Per epoch ? Per batch ? If it's at least of each class per batch, what if the batch size is 1 ? Or more generally what if the batch size is lower than the number of classes ?

Comment: I've updated the question